# How to trigger the file upload input in Angular?

Tags: angular

How to trigger the file upload input in Angular 4? I'm trying, but it's not working.

Instead of input button, I have to click on div and trigger the input type button.

app.html:

```html
<input id="custom-input" type="file" > 
<div (click)="myEvent(custom-input)">
    Click here to upload file
</div>
```

app.ts:

```ts
myEvent(event) {
    alert("event");
    event.nativeElement.click();
}
```

Answer (score 73):

1. Create the file upload input:

```html
<input 
    hidden 
    type="file" 
    #uploader
    (change)="uploadFile($event)"
/>
```

2. Create a button to trigger a click on the file input:

```html
<button (click)="uploader.click()">
    Upload
</button>
```

Then in your component you can use the `$event`:

```ts
uploadFile($event) {
    console.log($event.target.files[0]); // outputs the first file
}
```

Comment: working fine your code, but i am trying instead of button on div only because within the div i showing user selected png file, so again if i try to move or cropping the image means its trigger the function. so
how to prevent this scenario.

Comment: I don't know but in my case file selector open twice, any idea ?

Answer (score 6):

**HTML Template (attachment.component.html)**

```html
<input 
    style="display: none" 
    type="file" 
    multiple 
    (change)="onFileChanged($event)" 
    #fileInput
/>
<input 
    type="button" 
    class="upload-button" 
    value="Upload attachment(s)" 
    (click)="fileInput.click()" 
/>
```

**Handling in Typescript(attachment.component.ts)**

Third argument passed for the post call is for tracking the progress of upload using the event which we get subscribe to

```ts
onFileChanged(event) {
    const uploadData = event.target.files[0];
    this.http.post('url', uploadData, {
        reportProgress: true,
        observe: 'events'
    }).subscribe(event => {
        console.log('uploaded successfully');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could instead use a **label to style the button**.

**app.html**

```
<label id="custom-input">
       <input type="file" (click)="myEvent(custom-input)" hidden multiple />
       Click here to upload file
</label>
```

**app.ts**

```
uploadFile($event) {
    console.log($event.target.files[0]); // outputs the first file
}
```

However, ☝️ this function will not work as it needs to be **asynchronous** to await the user's input.

```
private checkUpload: any;

uploadFile(event) {
  // Check if file has been uploaded
  this.checkUpload = setInterval(() => {
    const checkFile = event.target.files[0];
    if (checkFile) {
      this.processFile(event);
    }
  }, 500);
}

// Runs after user uploads file;
processFile(event) {
  clearInterval(this.checkUpload);
  const fileInput = event.target.files[0];
}
```